# Application with elevated privileges is slow to load

Tags: c#, wpf

I am testing a C# WPF program that requires elevated privileges, that loads without any delay if I am logged on as an admin, but if I am logged on as a standard user (99% of time) then there is a delay of about 30 seconds before the UI appears.

Using the same elevation code in a C# console app and in a c# Winforms app, there is no delay in loading, so I know that the code works.
So, can anyone explain to me why is there a delay associated with WPF; and is there a workaround?

Here is the code from app.xaml.cs ( the remainder of the project is as genereated by VS2010)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;
using MyNewServiceLib;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WhySoSlow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            if (!IsAdmin())
            {
                StartAsAdmin(e);
                Application.Current.Shutdown();
            }
            else
            {
                MainWindow = new MainWindow();
                MainWindow.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
                MainWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
                MainWindow.Show();
            }
        }

        bool IsAdmin()
        {
            WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            WindowsPrincipal p = new WindowsPrincipal(id);

            return p.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        }

        private void StartAsAdmin(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] args = e.Args;
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                Uri uri = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
                startInfo.FileName = uri.LocalPath;
                startInfo.Arguments = String.Join(" ", args);
                startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
            }
            catch (Win32Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Further info**
Weirdly, if I start the program from a cmd prompt running under NT Authority\System, there is no delay starting up the UI. After that one successful start, every further start, from whatever prompt, be it standard user prompt, run as administrator, the program starts without delay; UNTIL that is, I log off from the session.
After logging on again to a new (standard user) session, all attempts to start the program result in the 30 second delay before showing the UI.
I can only think that this is some kind of UAC bodge by Microsoft, that is hindering the startup of wpf.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this code, have you tried utilizing a manifest file? Running an application as admin is one of the things you can do with it.

this might help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742884.aspx

Comment: Yes I added this line in app.manifest:
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
but this result was no different - slow to load

Comment: Also commented out the call to StartAsAdmin - no difference